# Bootstrap MVC How to center a brand

Tags: html, model-view-controller, center, navbar

i am trying to make the brand in the center of the navbar and i cant really make it.
i would be happy for some help.
Thanks

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#f7e351; background-image:linear-gradient(#f7e351,#f7e351,#f7e351); border-color:#e7c02f;">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f7e351;">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color:#f7e351;">
                <button type="button" style="background-color:#f7e351;" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span  class="icon-bar "></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("XXX", "Index", "XXX", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
             @Html.ActionLink("Brand", "Brand", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand active" })
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial2")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which link do you want center?  You have two actionlinks that have the class `navbar-brand`

Comment: The one which says "brand" in the actionlink

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/RLSkkAZG9l) for you so that you can see a visual of this working as expected.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#f7e351; background-image:linear-gradient(#f7e351,#f7e351,#f7e351); border-color:#e7c02f;">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f7e351;">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color:#f7e351;">
            <button type="button" style="background-color:#f7e351;" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand">Center</a>
        </div>
         <a class="navbar-brand brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.brand{
    position: absolute;
    left: 48.5%;
}
```

The words are overlapped because you didn't state your question which element with the `navbar-brand` class you wanted centered so I did both of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey! thank you very much! im afraid it didnt help, i probably have a problem with my code in a diffrent place.

Comment: @GilNave You're welcome, please mark this answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered